# Who was the storyteller in the movie Ink (2009)?

Tags: character-identification, ink-2009

I was watching one of my favorite movies, *Ink*, the other day, and it occurred to me that even after seeing it several times, there are still some parts that are unclear to me. Unfortunately, because it is not "mainstream", there is very little discussion on it, so finding answers about story and production is rather difficult.

[image]

Near the end, when Ink and the storyteller are talking, they have the
following exchange (Possible Spoiler?):

> **Storyteller**: Incredible Ink. You hide yourself ashamed... but you
>   can't see how beautiful you are.
>
> **Ink**: I don't understand. Why are
>   you here? What have you done?
>
> **Storyteller**: I'm here for you Ink. I'm here for you.
>
> **Ink**: Why? Why? What do you want from me? I am ruined. Why can't you
>   see that?
>
> **Storyteller**: Because I choose to see you... for what you were intended
>   to be... not for what you've become. When will you recognize her? Has
>   your mind become so corrupted?
>
> **Ink**: Who?
>
> **Storyteller**: This is what you could become. This is what you will
>   choose to be. You don't have to choose this.
>
> **Ink**: I don't understand. I don't understand.
>
> **Storyteller**: You know my name... but why?

And so, my question is, WHY does Ink know her name? Is it simply because she was well-known in the alternate plane, or is there more to it?

More specifically,

> is there a link between John's dead wife and the storyteller?

Comment: Awesome movie. It's been a while since I've seen the film so I'm not confident posting an answer, but I thought I'd share a thought from one fan to another. I never got the impression that the Storyteller was anyone other than the leader/uniting force for the good guys, but I guess one interpretation could be that she represented an idealized version of his daughter's potential future self - mirroring Ink's own nature.

Comment: Which from what I can recall (its been a while since I've seen the film last) is why the Incubi wanted her so badly - she represented an idealized paragon of hope, which is anathema to them.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 I never, ever, thought for a second that she could be an image of his daughter, but I absolutely love that idea.

Comment: Haha, honestly, as I said, it's been a while since I'd last seen the film, so it's possible I'm way off in that theory - which is why I didn't post it as an answer. I remember also getting the impression that she was some aspect of God, since she seems to be a leader/mother type to the... whatever the regular good guys were called. I think the implication was that they were angels or benevolent ghosts. Or something. Ink was as awesome as it was bizarre. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not made clear precisely what/who Liev is, nor her wider connection to Ink or the other characters. In short, the director has his own opinion about her, but not one that he's willing to share with the viewing audience.

> **Q. "You may be unwilling to state outright, but viewers the world over will no doubt be as curious as I am…who is Liev? (And is it
> deliberately “Veil” backwards?)”**
>
> **JW:** *"Wow, another thoughtful question. And I know what you’re getting at, but **that’s actually one question I’m going to leave open simply
> because I hate to alter someone else’s experience by adding my own
> commentary."***
>
> <sub><sup>[An interview with Ink’s Jamin Winans](https://www.benedictgarman.com/2013/05/16/an-interview-with-inks-jamin-winans/)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's rather disappointing to not have a more definitive answer, but it sure does help to at least know it was intentionally left open. Not sure how you found this so quickly. The Google is strong with you.

Comment: @TJames - It helps that I read this interview when the film first showed up

Comment: @TJames - As much as I hate to say this, you might want to hold fire on posting an acceptance. That quote is nearly four years out of date and the director may have shared something more recent that supersedes this answer. You don't want to scare people off of researching an answer by prematurely accepting

Comment: Good point, I'll give it few days. What's one less accepted answer in your enormous sea of points anyways  :P